# Vector Calculus - Minimizing integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis

Any hints or written techniques/steps for minimizing an integral? My textbook never mentions anything about it.

For example, find constants a, b,c, and d so that the integral of (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) from 0 to 2 would be minimized.

Thanks for help!

Comment: If there are no restrictions on $a,b,c,d$, we can just make them arbitrarily negative and get an arbitrarily negative value of the integral.

Comment: Set $a=1$, and minimize the integral of the square, and then you have an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can try the following

Solve the integral
2. Compute the first derivative or the solution
3. Solve for the zeros of the first derivative of the solution
4. Compute the second derivative at each zero. 
5. Any zero for which the second derivative is zero represents a local minimum.

Sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math.SE. If you want to format you maths you can use mathjax, see here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a tutorial. For information about our site, see our [faq] our [about] page.